# Get users "memberOf" AD-groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap, activedirectorymembership

I try to get all users "memberOf" all groups begining with "JE_"

I know that I cannot do the following:

memberOf=CN=JE*,OU=JE,OU=Gruppen,DC=subd,DC=dom,DC=net

But all the JE_* are located under a knot called "JE". Is it possible to get all users memberOf the groups located under the knot "JE"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes but you need to approach the problem differently. Rather than search against the user object you should search against teh group object with the user's DN.

For example, consider the user

```
cn=dave,OU=user,DC=subd,DC=dom,DC=net
```

The user is a member of several `JE*` groups.

```
CN=JE_1,OU=JE,OU=Gruppen,DC=subd,DC=dom,DC=net
CN=JE_2,OU=JE,OU=Gruppen,DC=subd,DC=dom,DC=net
CN=JE_3,OU=JE,OU=Gruppen,DC=subd,DC=dom,DC=net
```

In order to find the `JE*` groups to which the user belongs search for groups with a base of `OU=JE,OU=Gruppen,DC=subd,DC=dom,DC=net` and a search filter of

```
(&(objectclass=group)(member=cn=dave,OU=user,DC=subd,DC=dom,DC=net))
```

That will return all of the `JE*` group objects that contain the user in question. Ensure to specify that you only want the group name returned as an attribute otherwise all of the members will be returned too.  Not a problem if there are only a handful but it might be a nuisance if there are thousands.

Comment: Dave's answer should work but will not provide nested groups. For all groups including nested groups use something like: (&(objectclass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(CN=UserName,CN=Users,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET)))

Comment: @jeemster to work with ldapsearch: (&(objectclass=group)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=UserName,CN=Users,DC=Y‌​OURDOMAIN,DC=NET))